# How to get a customer field from adminCustomersController?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to get a customer field from the admin customer controller, like `$customer->name`, `$customer->lastname` or `$customer->email`, the same, but, with the rut.

In my knowledge, when we are here, the `$this` includes customer, or maybe i'm confused with others similars controllers.

Now the thing don't print anything

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is referring to the controller itself. Unless the controller has a rut property you are retrieving nothing.
If rut is a customer property i think you need to do

```
$customer = new Customer($id_customer_you_need);
$rut = $customer->rut;
```

replace the variable to the ID of the customer you need.

elseway if rut is a property of ClienteWs, you need to `$clienteWs->rut;`